# Anime where MC uses cards as weapons and ages backwards

Tags: story-identification, anime

Said anime has a white haired MC who ages backwards. He uses cards to fight. Using time to accelerate and decelerate the cards. He has a son about 16 who uses Water blades to fight, same system using time.

MC also has/had a wife who is now like him, aging backwards and has forgotten some memories, like her son, and she uses wind to fight.

The theme song is very catchy, and in the music video, the band plays cards against a masked figure, and as they lose they disappear, then the masked figure turns out to be a child, and is holding a big clock.

They also have a character who uses flames to fight.

All of the other one might be generic, but the MC using cards isn't that common.

Comment: You can click on the tiny "Add a comment" if you need to add few details to the question. Or you could click on the tiny "Edit" button to edit the question.

Comment: _"He uses cards to fight"_: something like Gambit's charged cards (from X-Men), or as in Yu-Gi-Oh?

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Chronos Ruler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9728290/)*** (2017)...?

> We all wish to go back in time, to turn back the clock and fix the past. But in this reality, that simple wish can bring about something deadly-demons who devour time! It's up to a group of strong warriors who fight using time manipulation to destroy these blights. Victor, Kiri, Mina, and Blaze have what it takes to maintain the balance of time as fighters-the Chronos Rulers.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronos_Ruler) for the show has descriptions of some of the characters -- including the white-haired main character, Victor Putin, his son, Kiri, his wife, Mīna, and another character called Blaze -- which are pretty close to your descriptions.

> **Victo is a 39 year old man who looks a lot younger as after the supposed death of his wife he made a deal with a Horologue, losing part of his time. That is why he now seeks to recover his lost time.** At first he did not believe that Mina is his wife but then begins to suspect that she could in fact be his wife. **As Chronos Ruler he is able to control the cards at will,** he is also in a UNIQUE position that allows him to use his powers without exhausting his time, due to the curse that the Horologue put on him when making the deal.

> **Kiri is the son of Victor Putin** and Mina Putin, he helps his father to recover his lost time. Like his father he did not believe that Mina could be his mother because he remembered his mother like Nana not Mina, but then like Victor he begins to suspect that she could be his mother. **As Chronos Ruler, he is able to control water** and he is also able to use a sword as a personal weapon. Due to him being the son of Mina, since she is a descendant of Chronos, he will not grow old.

> **She is the wife of Victor Putin** and mother of Kiri Putin, she believed herself dead but due to Victor's treatment she returns to life but like him she loses part of her time. At first she thought that she was only Victor's lover because she did not remember that she was married to him, nor did she remember that Kiri was her son, even though she cared about him. **As a Chronos Ruler she is able to control the air.** Due to being a direct descendant of Chronos her appearance does not change, even after having her time stolen, and why she looks like a young woman of 18 (although in the manga she looks younger) but then it is discovered that she may not have wasted her time after all.

> Blaze is 16, but in the manga he is 25, as a child he was a kind child who tried to help others but because his childhood friend was deceived, the villagers they thought that he was pretending to be a good boy, that's why he became the most evil person in the world, even though he is still young who likes to help his friends when necessary, he considers himself as Kiri's older brother, **as Chronos Ruler is able to control the fire.**